# Symfony3 entity-type not work

Tags: fosuserbundle, symfony-forms, symfony

FosUserBundle -> Overriding ProfileTypeForm.php

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->remove('username');
    $builder->add('Profile', MyProfileTypeForm::class, array(
        'mapped' => true,
        'label' => false,
        'required' => true,
        'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle',
    ));
}
```

MyProfileTypeForm.php File :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
   ....
   $builder
       ->add('firstname', TextType::class, array(
                'label' => 'form.profile.firstname',
                'constraints' => array(
                    new NotBlank(),
                    new Length(array('min' => 3))
                )
            ))
       ->add('country', CountryType::class, array(
                'label' => 'form.profile.country',
                'preferred_choices' => array(
                    'EN'
                )
            ))
       ->add('province', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'Panel\UserBundle\Entity\LocationProvince',
                'choice_label' => 'Province',
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $em){
                    return $em->createQueryBuilder('l')
                        ->orderBy('l.name');
                }
            ));
}
```

Error Code :

Neither the property 'Province' nor one of the methods `getProvince()`, `province()`, `isProvince()`, `hasProvince()`, `__get()` exist and have public access in class `Panel\UserBundle\Entity\LocationProvince`.

`Entity\LocationProvince` was created with the console and database update,schema was created.

`Province` is working smoothly when deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this:

```
->add('province', EntityType::class, array(
     'class' => 'AppBundle:LocationProvince',
     'choice_label' => 'Province',
     'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $em){
          return $em->createQueryBuilder('l')
                ->orderBy('l.name','ASC');
     }
));
```

See if that works...

Comment: Wow, I think it would be so simple, Thank You